# Hostapd access point + isc-dhcp-server disconnects client after 2 seconds of authenticating

Tags: dhcp, hot-spot, hostapd

I have Ubuntu 22.04 with a Wi-Fi access point Hostapd + isc-dhcp-server and every time I connect a client it automatically disconnects after 2 seconds.

Here are the contents of `/etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf`:

```
interface=wlp3s0
hw_mode=g
channel=10
ieee80211d=1
country_code=FR
ieee80211n=1
wmm_enabled=1
ssid=somename
auth_algs=1
wpa=2
wpa_key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
rsn_pairwise=CCMP
wpa_passphrase=somepassword
```

And of `/etc/dhcp/dhcpd.conf`:

```
option domain-name-servers 8.8.8.8, 8.8.4.4;
default-lease-time 600;
max-lease-time 7200;
authoritative;
subnet 10.10.10.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
  interface wlp3s0;
  range 10.10.10.100 10.10.10.125;
  option routers 192.168.1.1;
  option subnet-mask 255.255.255.0;
}
```

Output of `tail -f /var/log/syslog` (dummyuser):

```
Jan  9 00:19:15 user-Default-string hostapd: wlp3s0: STA b2:8a:00:11:22:33 IEEE 802.11: authenticated
Jan  9 00:19:15 user-Default-string hostapd: wlp3s0: STA b2:8a:00:11:22:33 IEEE 802.11: associated (aid 1)
Jan  9 00:19:15 user-Default-string hostapd: wlp3s0: STA b2:8a:00:11:22:33 RADIUS: starting accounting session 9B7BD58F3E6D8283
Jan  9 00:19:15 user-Default-string hostapd: wlp3s0: STA b2:8a:00:11:22:33 WPA: pairwise key handshake completed (RSN)
Jan  9 00:19:15 user-Default-string dhcpd[69049]: DHCPREQUEST for 10.10.10.102 from b2:8a:00:11:22:33 (OnePlus) via wlp3s0
Jan  9 00:19:16 user-Default-string dhcpd[69049]: DHCPACK on 10.10.10.102 to b2:8a:00:11:22:33 (OnePlus) via wlp3s0
Jan  9 00:19:16 user-Default-string dhcpd[69049]: reuse_lease: lease age 1 (secs) under 25% threshold, reply with unaltered, existing lease for 10.10.10.102
Jan  9 00:19:16 user-Default-string dhcpd[69049]: DHCPREQUEST for 10.10.10.102 from b2:8a:00:11:22:33 (OnePlus) via wlp3s0
Jan  9 00:19:16 user-Default-string dhcpd[69049]: DHCPACK on 10.10.10.102 to b2:8a:00:11:22:33 (OnePlus) via wlp3s0
Jan  9 00:19:20 user-Default-string hostapd: wlp3s0: STA b2:8a:00:11:22:33 IEEE 802.11: authenticated
Jan  9 00:19:20 user-Default-string hostapd: wlp3s0: STA b2:8a:00:11:22:33 IEEE 802.11: associated (aid 1)
Jan  9 00:19:20 user-Default-string hostapd: wlp3s0: STA b2:8a:00:11:22:33 RADIUS: starting accounting session 73F73824FEAE4501
Jan  9 00:19:20 user-Default-string hostapd: wlp3s0: STA b2:8a:00:11:22:33 WPA: pairwise key handshake completed (RSN)
Jan  9 00:19:20 user-Default-string dhcpd[69049]: reuse_lease: lease age 5 (secs) under 25% threshold, reply with unaltered, existing lease for 10.10.10.102
Jan  9 00:19:20 user-Default-string dhcpd[69049]: DHCPREQUEST for 10.10.10.102 from b2:8a:00:11:22:33 (OnePlus) via wlp3s0
Jan  9 00:19:20 user-Default-string dhcpd[69049]: DHCPACK on 10.10.10.102 to b2:8a:00:11:22:33 (OnePlus) via wlp3s0
Jan  9 00:19:20 user-Default-string dhcpd[69049]: reuse_lease: lease age 5 (secs) under 25% threshold, reply with unaltered, existing lease for 10.10.10.102
Jan  9 00:19:20 user-Default-string dhcpd[69049]: DHCPREQUEST for 10.10.10.102 from b2:8a:00:11:22:33 (OnePlus) via wlp3s0
Jan  9 00:19:20 user-Default-string dhcpd[69049]: DHCPACK on 10.10.10.102 to b2:8a:00:11:22:33 (OnePlus) via wlp3s0
Jan  9 00:19:21 user-Default-string wpa_supplicant[772]: wlp3s0: CTRL-EVENT-SCAN-FAILED ret=-95
Jan  9 00:19:25 user-Default-string hostapd: wlp3s0: STA b2:8a:00:11:22:33 IEEE 802.11: authenticated
Jan  9 00:19:25 user-Default-string hostapd: wlp3s0: STA b2:8a:00:11:22:33 IEEE 802.11: associated (aid 1)
Jan  9 00:19:25 user-Default-string hostapd: wlp3s0: STA b2:8a:00:11:22:33 RADIUS: starting accounting session 316751CEC6B74E1B
Jan  9 00:19:25 user-Default-string hostapd: wlp3s0: STA b2:8a:00:11:22:33 WPA: pairwise key handshake completed (RSN)
Jan  9 00:19:25 user-Default-string dhcpd[69049]: reuse_lease: lease age 10 (secs) under 25% threshold, reply with unaltered, existing lease for 10.10.10.102
Jan  9 00:19:25 user-Default-string dhcpd[69049]: DHCPREQUEST for 10.10.10.102 from b2:8a:00:11:22:33 (OnePlus) via wlp3s0
Jan  9 00:19:25 user-Default-string dhcpd[69049]: DHCPACK on 10.10.10.102 to b2:8a:00:11:22:33 (OnePlus) via wlp3s0
Jan  9 00:19:25 user-Default-string dhcpd[69049]: reuse_lease: lease age 10 (secs) under 25% threshold, reply with unaltered, existing lease for 10.10.10.102
Jan  9 00:19:25 user-Default-string dhcpd[69049]: DHCPREQUEST for 10.10.10.102 from b2:8a:00:11:22:33 (OnePlus) via wlp3s0
Jan  9 00:19:25 user-Default-string dhcpd[69049]: DHCPACK on 10.10.10.102 to b2:8a:00:11:22:33 (OnePlus) via wlp3s0
Jan  9 00:19:30 user-Default-string hostapd: wlp3s0: STA b2:8a:00:11:22:33 IEEE 802.11: did not acknowledge authentication response
Jan  9 00:19:42 user-Default-string hostapd: wlp3s0: STA b2:8a:00:11:22:33 IEEE 802.11: authenticated
Jan  9 00:19:42 user-Default-string hostapd: wlp3s0: STA b2:8a:00:11:22:33 IEEE 802.11: associated (aid 1)
Jan  9 00:19:42 user-Default-string hostapd: wlp3s0: STA b2:8a:00:11:22:33 RADIUS: starting accounting session 0CAAFD57300A938A
Jan  9 00:19:42 user-Default-string hostapd: wlp3s0: STA b2:8a:00:11:22:33 WPA: pairwise key handshake completed (RSN)
Jan  9 00:19:42 user-Default-string dhcpd[69049]: reuse_lease: lease age 27 (secs) under 25% threshold, reply with unaltered, existing lease for 10.10.10.102
Jan  9 00:19:42 user-Default-string dhcpd[69049]: DHCPREQUEST for 10.10.10.102 from b2:8a:00:11:22:33 (OnePlus) via wlp3s0
Jan  9 00:19:42 user-Default-string dhcpd[69049]: DHCPACK on 10.10.10.102 to b2:8a:00:11:22:33 (OnePlus) via wlp3s0
Jan  9 00:19:42 user-Default-string dhcpd[69049]: reuse_lease: lease age 27 (secs) under 25% threshold, reply with unaltered, existing lease for 10.10.10.102
Jan  9 00:19:42 user-Default-string dhcpd[69049]: DHCPREQUEST for 10.10.10.102 from b2:8a:00:11:22:33 (OnePlus) via wlp3s0
Jan  9 00:19:42 user-Default-string dhcpd[69049]: DHCPACK on 10.10.10.102 to b2:8a:00:11:22:33 (OnePlus) via wlp3s0
Jan  9 00:19:47 user-Default-string hostapd: wlp3s0: STA b2:8a:00:11:22:33 IEEE 802.11: authenticated
Jan  9 00:19:47 user-Default-string hostapd: wlp3s0: STA b2:8a:00:11:22:33 IEEE 802.11: associated (aid 1)
Jan  9 00:19:47 user-Default-string hostapd: wlp3s0: STA b2:8a:00:11:22:33 RADIUS: starting accounting session 8835AC9D55825E6F
Jan  9 00:19:47 user-Default-string hostapd: wlp3s0: STA b2:8a:00:11:22:33 WPA: pairwise key handshake completed (RSN)
Jan  9 00:19:47 user-Default-string dhcpd[69049]: reuse_lease: lease age 32 (secs) under 25% threshold, reply with unaltered, existing lease for 10.10.10.102
Jan  9 00:19:47 user-Default-string dhcpd[69049]: DHCPREQUEST for 10.10.10.102 from b2:8a:00:11:22:33 (OnePlus) via wlp3s0
Jan  9 00:19:47 user-Default-string dhcpd[69049]: DHCPACK on 10.10.10.102 to b2:8a:00:11:22:33 (OnePlus) via wlp3s0
Jan  9 00:19:47 user-Default-string dhcpd[69049]: reuse_lease: lease age 32 (secs) under 25% threshold, reply with unaltered, existing lease for 10.10.10.102
Jan  9 00:19:47 user-Default-string dhcpd[69049]: DHCPREQUEST for 10.10.10.102 from b2:8a:00:11:22:33 (OnePlus) via wlp3s0
Jan  9 00:19:47 user-Default-string dhcpd[69049]: DHCPACK on 10.10.10.102 to b2:8a:00:11:22:33 (OnePlus) via wlp3s0
```

The following lines also appear (always) in the log:

```
systemd[776074]: snap.snapd-desktop-integration.snapd-desktop-integration.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 6.
systemd[776074]: Stopped Service for snap application snapd-desktop-integration.snapd-desktop-integration.
systemd[776074]: Started Service for snap application snapd-desktop-integration.snapd-desktop-integration.
snapd-desktop-i[776798]: Not loading module "atk-bridge": The functionality is provided by GTK natively. Please try to not load it.
```

Comment: Welcome, please check the log (`tail -f /var/log/syslog`) while restarting the daemons and connecting

Comment: Done and posted.

Comment: two comments: first please disable the wpa_supplicant service. second: the client is properly connecting, gets an IP but there are no messeges about disconnecting, before reconnecting. unknown Reason.

Comment: I don't understand why I have to disable Wpa_supplicant. Is this service not necessary to establish the WiFi connection?
If I disable Wpa_supplicant I still have the same problem.
Is there a way to see more details in the log or another way to find the problem?

Answer (score 2):

> Problem solved.
>
> I have changed the gateway to one within the same range of the DHCP server and the clients no longer disconnect.

<sup>Answer moved here from [OP's question](https://askubuntu.com/revisions/1449281/3).</sup>